# Array dentro de um objeto, como é a sintaxe correta?

Tags: javascript

Estou criando um gerenciador de contas pessoais. Preciso fazer isso com localstorage. Ai estou tentando montar um objeto com todos os débitos de uma categoria (nesse ex. a categoria é bradesco).

```
{
"nameCategory": "Bradesco",
"arrayDebits": {
    ["GVT": {
        "value": "220,00",
        "PaymentDate": "10/10/2010"
    }, "Agua": {
        "value": "150,00",
        "PaymentDate": "15/15/2015"
    }]
}
```

Cada debito precisa ser um objeto, pensei em colocar o nome do objeto como o nome da conta (telefone GVT, conta de água, luz e etc) e o valor da conta e a data de vencimento como elementos dentro desse objeto. Porem essa sintaxe está errada segundo o site: [jsonlint](https://jsonlint.com/) dando este erro:

> Error: Parse error on line 3:
>   ... "arrayDebits": {        ["GVT": {           "value"
>   ----------------------^
>   Expecting 'STRING', '}', got '['

Estou errando aonde?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estás a usar sintaxe errada, com `[]` dentro de `{}`, o que queres é ao contrário, uma vez que `arrayDebits` é uma array com objetos dentro:

```
[{obj1}, {obj2}, etc...]
```

que ficaria assim:

```
{
  "nameCategory": "Bradesco",
  "arrayDebits": [
    {
      "GVT": {
        "value": "220,00",
        "PaymentDate": "10/10/2010"
      },
      "Agua": {
        "value": "150,00",
        "PaymentDate": "15/15/2015"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Vlw, mais porque eu preciso das chaves depois do [ e antes de fechar o ]?

Comment: @CarlosM `[ ]` quer dizer `array`. No exemplo em cima tens uma array, com 1 objeto dentro. Presumo que depois irás ter _N_ objetos certo, ou será somente 1? Caso seja só  1 não precisas de `[ ]` podes tirar e deixar só o objeto.

Comment: Eu quero que cada indice do array seja um objeto diferente... Pode ser assim? `{ "nameCategory": "Bradesco", "arrayDebits": [{ "GVT": { "value": "220,00", "PaymentDate": "10/10/2010" } }, { "Agua": { "value": "150,00", "PaymentDate": "15/15/2015" } } ] }`

Comment: @CarlosM sim, pode. Eu pensei que `GVT` e `Agua` seriam o mesmo, mas se não são assim funciona. Mas nesse caso, eu faria algo assim: em vêz de ter `Agua` e `GVT` fora do objeto interno faria: `{"nameCategory":"Bradesco","arrayDebits":[{"type":"GVT","value":"220,00","PaymentDate":"10/10/2010"},{"type":"Agua","value":"150,00","PaymentDate":"15/15/2015"}]}`

Comment: @CarlosM assim ^ é muito mais fácil de usar depois

Comment: show, vou usar assim... vlw!